# Riemann surfaces

Tags: riemann-surfaces, gt.geometric-topology

In Hatcher's book on Algebraic Topology, a lot of coverings of $S^1 \vee S^1$ has given. From these coverings, can we get different coverings of double torus (genus 2, compact surface)?

Comment: Certainly. Hatcher outlines how to compute all covering spaces of a given space in various ways. Covering spaces of surfaces restrict to covering spaces of their 1-skeletons for any CW-decomposition. 

Comment: You may get more responses if you put (a short version of) the question in the title.  Titles on MO can be about 50% longer than tweets.  Something like: "From a covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$, how can I get a covering of the two-hole torus?"

Comment: Just fatten the wedge of circles to be a pretzel. His construction still gives lots of covers. Just restrict them to the boundary to get covers of your genus two surface.